# Apache Camel Rename source file but do not move to .camel directory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-camel, spring-scheduled

Hi i'm using apache camel 2.9 with spring. My requirement is this.

camel looks for a file in a specific directory (e.g import) and the file format is this test_22-10-2015_p1.psv

After the file has been processed i need to rename the file to test_22-10-2015_p1_ACK.psv and keep it in the same folder without moving it to the .camel directory.

Is this possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes read the documentation about the file file component and you can find the `move` option.

- http://camel.apache.org/file2

You can use an expression to define the file name which uses the simple/file language

- http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html
- http://camel.apache.org/simple.html

So it would be something along the lines of

```
move=test_${file:name.noext}_ACK.${file:name.ext}
```

And then you need to make a exclude to skip files starting with `test_` as you move the file to the same directory.

```
exclude=test_.*
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Claus. i specify my URI in the deployment.properties and when i add the above move parameter to the uri it actually looks for ${file:name.noext} and ${file:name.ext} in the deployment properties. Is there a way to solve this. Much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'import.tariff.uri' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'file:name.noext'

Comment: Nevermind i can use $simple to avoid the clash. Thank you very much Claus